Discrepancy between SKR Mini E3V2 and documented SD Card Pinout
There is a schematic of the BTT SKR Mini E3 V2 available on the internet and I was taking a look at the SD Card Pinout.
First of all I noticed, that it appears to run in SPI and not SD mode. Fine okay, that matches my requirement, so the Dat1 and Dat2 pins are not used. Wait what? The SKR Mini E3 V2 circuit claims to not populate the Dat1 and CD/Dat3. But CD/Dat3 should be CD-CS according to what I found and IS used by the SPI interface according to the documentation I found so far. Now I am confused on what to implement on my project.
Here is an ascii table of the information to compare:
Pin Nr | SD      | SPI  | SKR-SPI | SKR-SD-Slot
1      | DAT2    | X    | X       | CD/DAT3
2      | CD/DAT3 | CS   | MISO    | MISO
3      | CMD     | DI   | GND     | GND
4      | VDD     | VCC  | SCK     | SCK
5      | CLK     | SCLK | 3.3V    | VDD     
6      | VSS     | VSS  | MOSI    | MOSI
7      | DAT0    | DO   | SSEL    | CD-CS
8      | DAT1    | X    | X       | DAT1

So according to the number of the pin on the Micro-SD card slot the same pins are not populated, however the naming says that the pins are completely different from what I found from multiple other sources. So what is now right? The combination Pin Nr + SD + SPI or the combination Pin Nr + SKR-SPI + SKR-SD-Slot? I plan to use a simple SPI interface like the SKR Mini series with the stm32f10x family of CPUs.
Edit: Please note, that we pretend a 1:1 mapping for the SD Slot. I am sure the internet means a 1:1 mapping for the pinout. I am just unsure what the SKR Schematic considers. Maybe they slapped the wrong symbol on and did not edit it, to fix the Names and they also follow the layout Pin Nr + SD + SPI?

We don't have data sheets for your SD card holders. Do you? They might use different pin numbering schemes. Also, which exact STM32F10X you intend to use - if the F103, it makes little sense to use SPI, as it has a native SD card controller.

Yeah, you are right, but please ignore the pinout of the SD slot and pretend it is 1:1 mapped. I am just unsure, if the schematic uses the wrong symbol for the SKR Mini E3 V2, or what is going on. As said, the SKR Schematic claims a completely different matching between the Pin Names of the Slot and what is documented in the internet. For example DAT0 from the original 1:1 mapping in the SKR schematic appears to be SSEL/CD-CS and the DAT3 pin appears to be unused. Not sure what causes the discrepancy. Maybe they just whacked on a wrong symbol on the schematic due to their different SD slot?

But that is the problem, we can't ignore and assume things. SD card sockets exist with different pin numberings, as they do not necessarily match the pin numbering of the SD card. For example, one of the connectors might have card detect sense switch and write protect sense switch numbered before th SD card pins. The pin numbers of two different sockets do not have to match. Do you have part numbers or data sheets for the connectors? If yes, this can be easily solved by reading them.

@Justme I use the F103, but I am not sure if I can give the 2 Pins away. I require quite a few pins for what I plan to do - CNC/Laser/3D Print controller with quite a few additional hardware features. I will work with Marlin, but in the end it will not be close to the SKR Mini E3 V2, it will be something completely different.

Which F103xx model you are using and does a version in larger package and more IO pins exist?

All that is required to solve this is to say, is the Pin Nr + SD + SPI layout correct for a 1:1 mapped SD slot. Yes or no? In this case I do not care at all for the SKR schematic. It just got me confused. I mean, SPI should be exactly one thing on an SD card, right? Or would SPI work with multiple different pinouts? If you could just clarify that it would be enough. Maybe both configurations are completely wrong, than please let me know. But I understand it as this: DAT1 is DO, CMD is DI Dat3 is CS and CLK is CLK. Right or wrong? Or does SD support a 4 Pin SD mode that SKR could use?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Please notice that the schematics use a component with pin numbering scheme that has 9 data pins which indicates standard size SD card, but the pins don't have two grounds. Also notice that the physical layout of a standard SD Card starts with pin 9, and then pins 1 to 8 are after it. So it might originally be a standard SD Card holder based on pin numbering, but naming may be incorrect.
But the pin numbering does not match MicroSD card pin number and count either.
If you look the pin names from pin 8 down to pin 1, they match the SD card pin usage in the order of pin 1 to pin 8.
It is possible that someone who made the schematic/pcb component marked the pin 1 to wrong edge or mirrored, which is a common error as the CAD drawings may show the pin order when looking from the bottom of the component. This may explain the error in the names.
It does not matter what the pin numbers or names on the card holder are, as long as you connect to the correct pins between the card and the MCU.
So it's simply an error, the pin numbers and names do not match an actual SD card. It was fixed by not redrawing the component but moving the MCU pins to correct places on the holder component. So correct pins from MCU still go to correct SD card pins. Just ignore the errors.

Be careful and always check the BOM - there are SD card slots that shuffle the pins internally or don't have a 1:1 mapping from the schematic numbers to the layout pads.

Yes, I understand that. But I am still not surem whether the pin names on the SKR Schematic are correct, or what the other documentation claims. Is DAT3 unconnected, or is it CS? DAT0 is not labled, is it just the SSEL or CD-CS Pin? Because the internet sais it should be DO. Not sure what to make of it.
